# How to create files and folders automatically through Terminal?

Tags: linux, windows, git, bash

How can the grouped/generalised Linux commands work on Windows env? (using Windows RT 2012). I am using Git BASH but can't achieve the following:

At the project root, I try the following to create lib folder and its subfolders

```
mkdir -p lib/{login, signup, users, posts}
touch !!:2/{package.json, index.js}
```

The one below works but I want to create these 2 files in each of the login, signup, users, posts folders

```
touch package.json index.js
```

Thanks

Edit : [Source](http://vimeo.com/56166857)

Comment: Please put the source from there you got this piece of stuff to question. :)

Comment: ok, thanks. src provided.

Answer (score 2):

**Spaces are the villains**

```
mkdir -p lib/{login,signup,users,posts} #no spaces in between comma & folder
touch !!:2/{package.json,index.js}
```

This expands as

```
touch lib/{login,signup,users,posts}/{package.json,index.js}
```

would work as expected.

Demystifying

```
touch !!:2/{package.json,index.js}
```

The `!!` expands to the last command run and `:2` expands to the third argument given that argument count starts from zero. Also, arguments are
separated by white-spaces by default. In

```
mkdir -p lib/{login, signup, users, posts}
```

the third argument turns out to be `lib/{login,` instead of expected `lib/{login,signup,users,posts}`, so the `touch` command expands as

```
touch lib/{login,/{package.json, index.js}
```

which is not the desired expansion

Comment: Does that work for `touch !!:2/${array[@]}` ?
Can't assign `array = (index.js config.json)` , Git BASH says unexpected token.

Comment: I grabbed the 2 commands from a tutorial they used on Mac. I have a remote Ubuntu 16.04 desktop and I tried both commands above and they don't work. Why can a Mac terminal allow that? Isn't that powerful? My Ubuntu desktop at home can't ? Alternative solution?

Comment: hmm i thought that was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't kill me for using `eval`...

```
dirs='lib/{login,signup,users,posts}';
files='{package.json,index.js}';
eval "mkdir -p $dirs";
eval "touch $dirs/$files";
find .;
## .
## ./lib
## ./lib/login
## ./lib/login/index.js
## ./lib/login/package.json
## ./lib/posts
## ./lib/posts/index.js
## ./lib/posts/package.json
## ./lib/signup
## ./lib/signup/index.js
## ./lib/signup/package.json
## ./lib/users
## ./lib/users/index.js
## ./lib/users/package.json
```